# Location of Microsoft Test Agent 2013 Config File

Tags: visual-studio-2013, automated-tests

I am working on setting up multiple tablets with the Microsoft Test Agents from 2013 where all of the tablets will have the same configuration.

I have one of the tablets setup so that it is talking to another tablet with the Test Controller (with the connection working successfully).

Since I have one of the tablets setup with the agent configuration I need, I was looking to copy all of the configuration files from that tablet to all of the others.

However, I haven't been able to find a file that holds the configuration.

I have tried:

1. Looking in the Agent install folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE. While there are files marked with "config", none of them contain the configuration values I set
2. Looking in the logger after applying the Test Agents settings. There were a few folder references, including C:\VSTFS. There is a file named "testagent.config" there, but that file also didn't include the values I set
3. I tried copying over all of the Test Agent files from the folder in step 1 to the same folder on a new tablet. But opening the Test Agent configuration on that tablet still displays as if no settings have been set (note that I installed the agent on another tablet, but didn't configure it on purpose)

Overall, I'm looking to do this to save time with configuring each tablet. I will ultimately have 25 tablets to configure, so I would prefer to configure each by just moving the files.

Does anyone know where I might be able to find the configuration file (if there is one) for the Test Agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this one QTControllerConfig.exe.config

Comment: Thanks Vitalii, it looks like all of the configuration of the agents is saved on the controller itself.

It does seem like there is somewhere else the values are saved too though since opening the Agent configuration tool while disconnected from the controller will still show the previously saved values.

However, I think I have a path to setting up the configuration of the other tablets now from the controller configuration file. Thanks again!